# Change label on default Wordpress "Lost password page"

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to change the default label for the Wordpress lost password form which says "Username or E-mail". I need it to just read "Email" and I don't want to edit any core Wordpress files. I've already achieved this for the default login form using:

```
global $pagenow; 
if ($pagenow==='wp-login.php') { 
  add_filter( 'gettext', 'user_email_login_text', 20, 3 );

  function user_email_login_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ($translated_text === 'Username') {
        echo $translated_text;
        $translated_text = 'Email';
    }

    return $translated_text;
  }

}
```

And this seems to also work on the other default forms for labels consisting of **single words**. However, if I augment the `if` condition to include `| $translated_text === 'Username or e-mail'` it doesn't work.

Any ideas? I really don't want to have to code a bespoke form as this doesn't fit in with how my system works.

Also, I wonder why Wordpress spells "Email" as "E-mail" on the lost password form, but without the dash on all other forms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you allready solved this. Anyway your code is allmost correct. You were only missing that the string is case sensitive and to include the colon. Like this: `if ($translated_text === 'Username or E-mail:')`

No need to echo `$translated_text` either

This works on my installation:

```
global $pagenow; 
if ($pagenow==='wp-login.php') { 
  add_filter( 'gettext', 'user_email_login_text', 20, 3 );
  function user_email_login_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    if ($translated_text === 'Username or E-mail:') {

        $translated_text = 'Email';
    }

    return $translated_text;
  }

}
```